# Making itemize completely disappear

Tags: beamer

I am doing a presentation with Beamer and I have this code

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1-3>{First title}
\frametitle<4->{Second title}

\onslide<1->
\[
formula
\]
\onslide<2-3>
  \begin{itemize}
      \item<2-> first item
      \item<3-> second item
  \end{itemize}
\onslide<4->%
  something here \\
\onslide<5->%
  something else here \\
\onslide<6->%
  something else here \\
\onslide<7->%
  something else here 
\end{frame}
```

What I would like is to make the `itemize` completely disappear after slide 3, so that things from slide 4 take its place. With my code, the `itemize` does disappear but the second part of the content starts appearing below the space once occupied by it.

And, very important, the formula in the top part of the slide should not wobble. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible, but with ugly jumps on the screen

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see... I did not expect it to be so difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using `\only` leads to the jumping problem, but you can wrap stuff in an `{overlayarea}` environment to prevent that:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1-3>{First title}
\frametitle<4->{Second title}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{2cm}
\onslide<1->
\[
formula
\]
\only<2-3>{
  \begin{itemize}
      \item<2-> first item
      \item<3-> second item
  \end{itemize}
  }
\end{overlayarea}
\onslide<4->%
  something here \\
\onslide<5->%
  something else here \\
\onslide<6->%
  something else here \\
\onslide<7->%
  something else here 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks: this works perfectly. I had tried before with `overprint` but did not manage to obtain the correct result